# Regular permutation groups and 2-closure

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, algebraic-graph-theory

I'm currently working through Dobson, Malnič, Marušič's *Symmetry in Graphs* (2022), and am trying to prove the following proposition (pp. 208):

**Exercise 5.2.1** If $G \leqslant \text{Sym}(\Omega)$ is a regular permutation group, then $G=G^{(2)}$, i.e. $G$ is 2-closed.

Given that $G^{(2)}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{|\Omega|-1}\text{Aut}(\Gamma_i)$, where $\Gamma_i$ are the orbital digraphs of $G$, my approach to prove 5.2.1 has been to determine the structure of an orbital digraph of a regular permutation group (a union of disjoint directed cycles, according to my working). However I'm unsure if this is a right approach, as the notion of 2-closure is fairly new to me.

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha,\beta \in\Omega$, let $\Gamma$ be the orbital digraph containing the directed edge $\alpha \to \beta$.

Since the stabilizer $G_\alpha$ of $\alpha$ in $G$ is trivial, this is the only edge in $\Gamma$ with source $\alpha$. So any element in ${\rm Aut}(\Gamma)$ that fixes $\alpha$ must fix $\beta$. So no element in $G^{(2)}$ fixes both $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Since $G \le G^{(2)}$,  $G^{(2)}$ is transitive with trivial point stabilizers, and hence $G = G^{(2)}$.

Comment: Thank you. Very clear. I got too caught up with fine details to realise showing $|G^{(2)}|=|G|$ is sufficient.

Comment: You can't use $|G^{(2)}| = |G|$ because $G$ could be infinite, but the fact that $G^{(2)}$ has trivial stabilizers implies that $G = G^{(2)}$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I was thinking of finite groups. I believe I see how this works. If there is $a \in G^{(2)}$ with $a \notin G$, then there are $x,y \in \Omega$ and $b \in G^{(2)}\backslash\{a\}$ such that $a(x,y)=b(x,y)$, meaning $b^{-1}a \in G^{(2)}_{(x,y)}={1}$, meaning $b=a$, a contradiction.